# How did i can upgrade from jboss4.2.3GA to Wildfly?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-4.2.x

We had deployed jboss4.2.3GA in 2012,and now we want to upgrade to Wildfly,but now we have no sufficient technical to do that.so someone can tell what we can to step by step ? and are there any technology guide?

We have compared the document structures of the two versions, but they are far different. So we want to find a guide that can actually guide us step by step. I wonder if there is such a document?

Comment: 4.2.3 was released in 2008.  14 years of changes will not be a quick process and will be especially hard if you don't have the expertise on staff.  You're likely to want to rewrite portions - perhaps large portions - of your code to take advantage of newer technologies.  I would strongly recommend hiring an expert for this process as it will be a good amount of work.

Comment: Do you tell me where there is an expert?

Comment: Reach out to me - my email is my user name @gmail.com

Comment: I have sent mail to you,my email is 2251910574